# Calculating Pi in Clojure

Tags: beginner, clojure, floating-point

Obviously there are better ways of obtaining Pi, but for educational purposes, how is the code below?

```
(defn leibniz-numerator [x] (* (- (rem x 4) 2) -4.0))

(defn calc-pi-leibniz
    "Calculate pi with Leibniz formula
    4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 etc
    Very slow convergence"
    [terms]
    (reduce + (map #(/ (leibniz-numerator %) %) (range 1 terms 2))))

(print (calc-pi-leibniz 10000000))
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd say your solution is pretty good! Since you probably won't re-use your `leibniz-numerator` function, you might want to make it private by declaring it with `defn-`, or you could declare it within the body of your main function using `let` or `letfn`.

Also, you might notice that your function actually computes pi with half the number of terms given has parameters (might not be of importance).

I can share some alternatives I came up with.

We could start by generating the sequence `(4 -4 4 -4...)`. To do that, we can use the method `iterate`:

```
(take 4 (iterate - 4))
;;=> (4 -4 4 -4)
```

Then we want the sequence `(1 3 5 7)`. You already found method `range`for that:

```
(take 4 (range 1 10 2))
;;=> (1 3 5 7)
```

If you divide those to element wise, you will get `(4 -4/3 4/5 -4/7...)`. You can do that with `map`

```
(take 4 (map / (iterate - 4) (range 1 10 2)))
;;=> (4 -4/3 4/5 -4/7)
```

In our final computation, this can get really slow because we're using decimals. Let's use floats instead, and put everything together:

```
(defn calc-pi-leibniz [terms]
  (reduce + (map / (iterate - 4.0) (range 1.0 terms 2.0))))
```

But for some reason, this is 5 times slower than your solution. If someone could tell me why, I'd be grateful. I suspect that is because map has to go through two lists instead of one, but since they are both lazy this should not matter?

For a faster solution (but less elegant), we can see that there are two subsequences in the leibniz formula. One that is `(4 4/5 4/9)` and one that is `(-4/3 -4/7 -4/11)`. With that in mind, you can get the following:

```
(defn calc-pi-leibniz [terms]
  (* 4 (- (reduce + (map / (range 1.0 terms 4.0)))
          (reduce + (map / (range 3.0 terms 4.0))))))
```

Which runs as fast as your solution.